# Can you have a popup window without going to a new page in php?

Tags: php

I am trying to get a popup window to come up after the user uploads a picture. I got the window to popup the only thing is it first takes them to a new page. I would like the window to popup without taking the user to a new page first.

Here is my code

```
<?php

$target_dir = "../images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if ($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 30000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if ( $imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png"
    && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif") 
{
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file " . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) . " has been uploaded.";
        copy($target_file, 'images/' . $target_file);
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

Comment: PHP is server-side, so to make it do anything you need to call the server, which is either done with a form submit (which creates a new page) or using Ajax, which does not necessarily create a new page. I suspect you need to use Ajax to submit the picture to your PHP code, that will then be able to pop up a modal window to update the user without dismissing the original page.

Comment: A pupup windows, is in fact usually a simple `<div>` which is initially invisible and is then populated and made visible and positioned using javascript

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, You can !

---

PHP is server-side, but you **STILL** can use **CLIENT SIDE code**.

## Here is how we would make a popup using php :

```
<body>
<div class="popup">
    <div class="popup-content">
        <span>Hello World</span>
        <p>This is my very very cool popup !</p>
        <button onclick="closePopup();"></button>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function closePopup {
        var popup = document.querySelecter(".popup");
        popup.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

Here is the html code with some Javascript , First of all i'd recommend trying the code and working with the css so it looks good.

---

## Adding it to php

---

```
<?php
echo '<body>
    <div class="popup">
        <div class="popup-content">
            <span>Hello World</span>
            <p>This is my very very cool popup !</p>
            <button onclick="closePopup();"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function closePopup {
            var popup = document.querySelecter(".popup");
            popup.style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>
</body>';
```

So You can always echo out some Html code.

### Other way?

---

Yep ! We even have another way. We are going to use Javascript

```
<body>
    <div class="popup">
        <div class="popup-content">
            <span>Hello World</span>
            <p>This is my very very cool popup !</p>
            <button onclick="closePopup();"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function openPopup() {
            var popup = document.querySelecter(".popup");
            popup.style.display = "block";
        }

        function closePopup() {
            var popup = document.querySelecter(".popup");
            popup.style.display = "none";
        }

        closePopup();
    </script>
</body>

<?php


if(1 === 1) 
{
    echo "openPopup();";
}

 ##
```